# Why am I not able to access the express server from a different file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have set up an express server as follows (inside of `server.js` ) :

```
const app = express();
.........
.....
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
);
module.exports = server;
```

Inside of another file `socket.js`:

```
const server = require("./server");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const io = socketio(server);
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("A user just joined!");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A socket just left!");
  });
});
```

For some reason I get an error in my console while trying to connect to the socketio on the client:

`GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N8-d7Q4 404 (Not Found)`

The error does not occur if I execute everything in a single file (without exporting the server):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
);
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const io = socketio(server);
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("A user just joined!");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A socket just left!");
  });
});
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Does module.exports not work with the express server or is this is a socketio issue ?

Comment: How are you running your application? I presume you're running it as `node socket.js` right?

Comment: I wonder if you have a circular dependency?  When you do this: `const server = require("./server");` in `socket.js`, then add `console.log(server)` right after it to verify that you actually got the server object there.

Comment: @slebetman I am running it as an npm app so npm run dev uses the same endpoint as the socket connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems like theres nothing showing up in my terminal console when I do console.log(server) . I was wondering if it's impossible to module.exports = server at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're not loading `socket.js` at all.  When you had only the one file, you just did `node app.js` and that would work fine.  But, if you do `node app.js` with your two files, then there's nothing to ever load `socket.js` at all.  In fact, the way you have the two files laid out, you would have to do:

```
node socket.js
```

to initialize things.  Then, `socket.js` does a `require('./app.js')` to get app.js loaded.

> I was wondering if it's impossible to module.exports = server at all

Yes, you can freely export the server and you are exporting it.

---

Another way of doing things is to still have `app.js` be your main file that you load to start up your app and you load `socket.js` from there and pass it the `server` object so it can use it.

```
// app.js

const server = const server = app.listen(...);

// load socket.js and pass it our server
require('./socket.js')(server);
```

Then in socket.js:

```
// socket.js

const socketio = require("socket.io");

module.exports = function(server) {
     const io = socketio(server);
     // rest of your module code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response. I'm a bit new to express so it seems like I got my understanding of exports wrong so please correct me if I am wrong:
I always thought if you have any var or const in your project which works like an 'app', you just needed to module.exports = item and then in the file where you want to use it just require('item') would be enough. I have been doing this throughout for all my files (including mongoose.schemas). So could you please explain why it's different with the 'const server' ? Is it because in this case server is treated more like an executable?

Comment: @RahulPillai - If you were starting your app with `node app.js`, then NOTHING ever caused `socket.js` to get loaded.  Nothing ever required it.  So, it never got executed.  There's nothing at all special about exporting `server`.  You just didn't ever load your new module.

Comment: I read my code again in detail and I see what you mean now. I sort of tried to "imitate" what I did with mongoose schema before this (simply exporting the schema and using it in another file) but that wouldn't necessarily work here because of what you mentioned - exporting it doesn't really "run" it. That makes sense. Thanks a lot :)